# How to set Assets json file data in two spinner + android?

Tags: android, json

Json File:

```
{
"Iraq":["Baghdad","Karkh","Sulaymaniyah","Kirkuk","Erbil","Basra","Bahr","Tikrit","Najaf","Al Hillah","Mosul","Haji Hasan","Al `Amarah","Basere","Manawi","Hayat"],

 "Lebanon":["Beirut","Zgharta","Bsalim","Halba","Ashrafiye","Sidon","Dik el Mehdi","Baalbek","Tripoli","Baabda","Adma","Hboub","Yanar","Dbaiye","Aaley","Broummana","Sarba","Chekka"]
}
```

I need to display country name in first spinner and city name in second spinner as per selected countries of spinner.

How to code it android?

My Code:

public class Search_for_room extends Activity {

```
JSONObject jsonobject;
JSONArray jsonarray;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayList<String> worldlist;
ArrayList<CollegeList> world;
String value,key;
List<String> al;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
HashMap<String, String> m_li  = new HashMap<String, String>();
public  ArrayList<SpinnerModel> CustomListViewValuesArr = new ArrayList<SpinnerModel>();
CustomAdapterStatus customAdapter;
Search_for_room activity = null;
Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_for_room);
    activity = this;
    ArrayList<String> items=getCountries("countriesToCities.json");
    spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spCountry);
    spinnerCity=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spCity);
}

private ArrayList<String> getCountries(String fileName){
    JSONArray jsonArray=null;
    ArrayList<String> cList=new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open(fileName);
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] data = new byte[size];
        is.read(data);
        is.close();
        String json = new String(data, "UTF-8");
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);

       // JSONObject resultObject = jsonObj.getJSONObject("result");
        System.out.print("======Key: "+jsonObj);

        Iterator<String> stringIterator = jsonObj.keys();
        while(stringIterator.hasNext()) {
            key = stringIterator.next();
            value = jsonObj.getString(key);
            System.out.println("------------"+key);
            m_li.put(key,value);
            al = new ArrayList<String>(m_li.keySet());

            final SpinnerModel sched = new SpinnerModel();

            /******* Firstly take data in model object ******/
            sched.setCountryName(value);
            //   sched.setImage(key);
            sched.setStates(key);

            /******** Take Model Object in ArrayList **********/
            CustomListViewValuesArr.add(sched);
            Resources res = getResources();
            customAdapter = new CustomAdapterStatus(activity, R.layout.spinner_item, CustomListViewValuesArr,res);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }catch (JSONException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        /*jsonArray=new JSONArray(json);
        if (jsonArray != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                System.out.pri
                //cList.add(String.valueOf(jobj.keys()));
            }
        }*/
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cList;
}
```

}

Comment: What you tried so far ??

Comment: I update my question and Ad code so can you please see it and reply me back?

Answer (score 0):

**try this code it can help you**

```
 try {
        // load json from assets    
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());

        // than get your both json array
        JSONArray IraqArray = obj.getJSONArray("Iraq");
        JSONArray LebanonArray = obj.getJSONArray("Lebanon");

        // declare your array to store json array value
        String Iraq[] = new String[IraqArray.length()];
        String Lebanon[] = new String[LebanonArray.length()];

         //get json array of   Iraq
        for (int i = 0; i < IraqArray.length(); i++) {
            Iraq[i] = IraqArray.getString(i);
        }
         //get json array of   Lebanon
        for (int i = 0; i < LebanonArray.length(); i++) {
            Lebanon[i] = LebanonArray.getString(i);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**ask me in case of any query**

Comment: I want to add country names in spinner and on the base of that i want to set city names. Here there is only two countries for example of json but there is number of long list in json

Comment: than send all your json and above code is jsut sample hoe to read json from assets

Comment: can your share all your json

Comment: Json file data is to log almost 190 country lists are there so I am not able it put it in question, but I shared demo of that json file in my question only

Comment: Please check mail, I send it to you

Answer (score 0):

add menu item in spinner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:title="Select Week"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

add your json to array list

```
 public void onPostExecute(String response) {
        try {
            list.clear();
            MatchData vid = null;
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("items");
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                vid = gson.fromJson(array.getJSONObject(i).toString(), MatchData.class);

                list.add(vid);
            }
            matchDataAdapter = new MatchDataAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(matchDataAdapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

finally set adapter to spinner

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.android_action_bar_spinner_menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);  

        **ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lists);**
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selected = (String) parent.getSelectedItem();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),selected,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                week = Integer.parseInt(selected);
                requestforinfo();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You had done everything correct uptil now. Just make my suggestion and you are good to go with long list of JSON data.

First make the JSON Response of file accessible to whole activity/fragment by declaring at top.

Added following function to retrieve cityList of particular country:

```
private ArrayList<String> getCityList(String countryName){
    ArrayList<String> cityList = new ArrayList<>();

    //Here jsonObj is the your JSON response from the file.
    try {
        JSONArray jArray =jsonObj.getJSONArray(countryName);

        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            cityList.add(jArray.getString(i));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return cityList;
}
```

Then add on spinnerItemSelected call the below function:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selected = ((SpinnerModel) parent.getSelectedItem()).getCountryName();

         //For sake of your answer I had used String Array and ArrayAdapter. You can modify as you want.
           ArrayAdapter<String> cityAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(YourActivity.this, R.layout.single_textview,getCityList(selected));
           spinnerCity.setAdapter(cityAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```